# How can I programmatically copy all blocks of a given theme into the same regions of a new theme?

Tags: 8, blocks

I would like to switch admin themes from a core theme (seven) to a custom sub-theme so I can add some customization without hacking core.

When I install the new sub-theme it creates all the block placement settings and leaves them header or content. I haven't changed any regions between the two themes, and just want to copy all the blocks from the seven theme to the current theme. I know I can check block settings with block plugin manager (`plugin.manager.block`) but I don't know what blocks to edit. I would like to know how to get a list of all the blocks from the old theme and copy all the placement to new theme programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can entity query your relevant block config then create a cloned entity object via [`Block::createDuplicateBlock()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21src%21Entity%21Block.php/function/Block%3A%3AcreateDuplicateBlock/8.2.x) then modify the sub-theme clones before saving the new block config into sub-theme region.

For example:

```
$block_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('block')->condition('theme', 'my_base_theme')->condition('region','my_region')->execute();
foreach ($block_ids as $block_id) {
  $parent_block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);

  $new_id = str_replace('my_base_theme', 'my_sub_theme', $parent_block->get('id'));
  $child_block = $parent_block->createDuplicateBlock($new_id, 'my_sub_theme');
  // @TODO: set other properties that might need to be unique to this new theme's block

  $child_block->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before but it's been a while. First, make sure the regions match between your two themes. I think this is what I did:

- Export configs:

```
$ drush cex
```

- Use text editor to locate all of the config files that start with `block.block...`.
- Run a bulk find `theme: seven` and replace with `theme: subtheme`.
- Delete the `uuid: ...` line from each of the updated config files.
- Import configs:

```
drush cim
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am asking how to this in an update hook programmatically.

Comment: @FrankRobertAnderson – Maybe add that for clarification to your question.

Comment: The post already says that I am asking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: I apologize, @FrankRobertAnderson, sometimes I see programmatically and I just think "not with the GUI." Shawn Conn's answer seems like more the approach you need.

Comment: No need to apologize @IsaiahNixon